# Confused about a missing $\pm$ sign in texbook's answer (simple quadratic equation)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, word-problem

The problem goes like this:

> Working together, two cranes unload a barge in $t$ hours. What time does it take for each crane to unload the same barge on its own, provided that crane 1 spends $a$ less hours doing that?

My solution:

Let's say the barge's load is 1 unit of cargo.

The first crane's unloading speed is $V1$, the second's $V2$

When the two cranes work together, their unloading time is $t$:
$$\frac{1}{V1+V2}=t;$$
$$\frac{1}{t}=V1+V2$$

When they work separately, the first crane spends $a$ less hours unloading the barge:

$$\frac{1}{V1}=\frac{1}{V2}-a$$

Since our task is to find their standalone times, let's say $\frac{1}{V1}$ equals $x$, then $\frac{1}{V2}=x+a$. Then 
$$V1=\frac{1}{x}; V2=\frac{1}{x+a}$$

Then we get
$$\frac{1}{t}=V1+V2;$$
$$\frac{1}{t}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x+a}$$

This is easily transformed into a quadratic equation:

$$x^2+x(a-2t)-ta=0$$

The solution to which is
$$x=\frac{-a+2t\pm\sqrt{a^2+4t^2}}{2}$$

This is the time the first crane spends to unload the barge on its own. To find the second crane's time, we only need to add another $a$, so to shorten the answer we could just put a plus-minus sign before $a$:

$$x=\frac{\pm{a}+2t\pm\sqrt{a^2+4t^2}}{2}$$

But the textbook's answer lacks the $\pm$ sign before the square root:

[image]

Why?

Comment: most likely one of the answers gives a negative time. in a word problem, nonsensical answers like this can be discarded.

Comment: @ElliotG - I see, thank you, Elliot. So I need to prove that $(-a+2t)$ will always be less than $\sqrt{4t^2+a^2}$

Comment: I wonder how does one prove that..

Comment: The latter term is always greater than $2 \cdot t$ and the former term is less than it.  Assuming $a$ and $t$ are positive!

Comment: @DanBrumleve - thank you! Now I see it. (0:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other solution, where one of the cranes works at a negative rate, is physically reasonable but economically unintended.

The interpretation is that crane 2 is loading while crane 1 is reversing some of that work, by unloading.

Comment: Exactly! I've just tried to prove the negativity in a separate answer. (0:

Comment: The constant term of the quadratic in $x$ is $-at$ which is negative.  So one positive and one negative value of $x$ will satisfy the equation.  The sum $V_1 + V_2$ is constrained to be positive (if $t > 0$) so that the total rate of loading when they work together is positive.

Comment: Oh, so if a quadratic's constant term is negative, one of its solutions will be negative?

Comment: Yes, the constant term is the product of the two roots, if the quadratic is normalized so that the coefficient of the $x^2$ term is $1$.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it follows from (the?) [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Answer (score 0):

Per Elliot G.'s helpful suggestion, we need to prove that

$$2t-a < \sqrt{a^2+4t^2}$$

Let's square both sides:

$$4t^2-4at+a^2 < a^2+4t^2;$$
$$-4at<0$$

Since we know from the problem's formulation that $a$ and $t$ are both positive, the inequality will always be true. This means that if we retain the $\pm$ sign in the answer, one of the two solutions will result in a "negative" time, which is unacceptable. Thus we can safely discard the minus part of the $\pm$ sign.